# “Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch” error message

Tags: vba, runtime-error

Good afternoon.

I’m new at `VBA`. From my research on the internet, I’ve been able to add some lines that display a message box when an `NG` is entered into a cell within the range. However, when I try to delete the inputs from several cells, I get a `Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch` message. Any ideas what I’m doing wrong and how to fix it? I’ve added the code that I put in `VBA` below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("I3:JY30")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Value <> "NG" Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "ATTENTION: If bell cup is No Good, please replace with new cup and notify supervisor/leader for review. Also, document bell cup serial number and concern on worksheet titled Scrap Bell Tracking "
End Sub
```

Also, when I click Debug, the `If Target.Value <> "NG" Then` is highlighted.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`Target` is a Range, and hence it may consist of more than one cell. In that case, the `Value` property is invalid.

A simple solution would be to ignore changes with more than one cell: For that, we need to add the following before the access to the `Value` property:

```
If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
```

But that would not show a message if e. g. the user pastes five cells, and one or more of them contain the text. The perfect solution would be looping through the range and check each cell separately. And then you would have to think if you want to show the message more than one time if the text is found in more than one cell. So, I will leave that as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: Thanks. I thing that is still past my current abilities, but I'll keep trying.